Workflow implementation using SQL Server Agent
I inherited a project that has a workflow implemented as a series of SQL Agent jobs in SQL Server 2019.
Objects have a certain status and the jobs look for objects with that are currently in their start status, work on them, and move it to the next status
There's a current status table and a history table.  The current status table has a primary key on the object id; the history table has non-clustered, non-unique indexes in the object id
CREATE TABLE CurrentStatus (
ObjectID bigint primary key,
StatusID smallint,
UpdateDate DATETIME
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ixCurrentStatus-StatusID] ON [dbo]. [CurrentStatus]
([StatusID] ASC)

CREATE TABLE StatusHistory (
ObjectID bigint,
StatusID smallint,
ErrorMsg varchar(max),
UpdateDate DATETIME)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ndxStatusHistoryUpdateDate] ON [dbo].[StatusHistory]
([UpdateDate] ASC)
INCLUDE([StatusID])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20180906-190017] ON [dbo].[StatusHistory]
([ObjectID] ASC)

Both tables also have an index on the StatusID column.
Each job step has code that looks like this:
DECLARE @worklist TABLE (ObjectID bigint)
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TOP (@batchSize) CurrentStatus SET StatusID=@newstatus, UpdateDate=GetDATE()
OUTPUT inserted.ObjectID into @worklist
WHERE StatusID=@oldStatus

INSERT INTO StatusHistory
SELECT ObjectID, @newStatus, GetDATE()
FROM @worklist
COMMIT TRANSACTION

Recently I was looking at some logs and seeing that every now and then the various steps would deadlock on each other, and I was surprised by that.  I mean, the batches are small and the different status ids shouldn't be stepping on each other.
First thing I noticed was that the index on the StatusID wasn't getting used.  The plan was doing a table scan on ObjectID.  Here's the link to Ozar's share the plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJZBSbmHyl
Didn't want to disrupt the running process, so I was using Display Estimated Execution Plan to try some variations (like supplying a hint to use the StatusID column on the first lookup).  The estimated plan  said it would be more expensive (which I found counterintuitive since the StatusID would be highly selective).  As one might imagine, 99.9% of the rows in the CurrentStatus table end up in the "Done" state; as a proportion of the values in the statusid dictionary, any non-Done state would be highly selective.  The batch size is a parameter, defaults to 200 but is more commonly in the 50 range.
But it got me wondering about other approaches and how they would perform.  I know, I know "try it yourself" but I thought this would be a fairly common pattern and I could ask some "best practices" type questions.

Would it be better to have @worklist declare ObjectID as a primary key and have an initial SELECT statement that would use the StatusID index?  Then the very small worklist table seems like it would be better oriented for the update of current and the insert into history.
Would that maintenance of Current and History be better as 1 statement (UPDATE Current OUTPUT inserted.* INTO History) or as 2 separate statements?  I've seen a couple old Oflow articles implying that UPDATE A OUTPUT inserted.* INTO B had some kind of extra overhead)

Thanks

Please ask a single, specific question - at a minimum you need to ask two questions as written. But any question that asks "what is better" is very likely to get closed as opinion based - because the true answer is almost certainly "it depends". I suggest showing the deadlock graph and asking for help to stop the deadlock - that is specific.

The "bad" plan might be cached because @oldStatus isn't known until runtime for sql server, you could try adding option(recompile) or optimize for ... to make it check the plan. You could remove the variable and use the actual value, since it's known for each step i guess too.

I would interpret this question as "how to avoid the deadlocks" along with a couple of ideas that might or might not help. Without seeing the specifics of the deadlocks and the other involved DML, it is hard to offer specific advise. However, if @batchSize is small enough so that the seek and update operation is quick, I would be inclined to just put a TABLOCK or TABLOCKX hint in the UPDATE statement. (Others more knowledgeable than I might disagree.) Small delays in batch operations are usually tolerated, but this might also add a slight delay from online add-new-work processes.

I personally see no problem with the two-step UPDATE/OUTPUT and INSERT process you have in place, unless you have another process somewhere with a transaction that first accesses the history and then attempts to modify the status table. And again, if @batchSize is small, I would do all I can to encourage the use of the StatusID index - up to and including adding an index hint. (Here, I'm sure opinions will differ.) I just have an aversion to table scans, unless I know most/all rows are actually needed. One last thought: Double check that StatusID and @oldStatus are the same type.

Please share your execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Also if you could paste in a deadlock XDL/XML graph  that would be great.

Also "Both tables also have an index on the StatusID column." please show, do they have INCLUDEs and are they unique?

Thank you for everyone taking the time to respond.  I've edited the text to add the additional information

TL;DR;
This is mostly caused by Halloween Protection, which is demanding a blocking operator between read and write phases in order to use the index. So instead of doing a blocking Sort as it commonly does, it decides to fallback to a Clustered Index Scan, which doesn't require a blocking operator as it has no Halloween issues.
Combining the two operations into a single OUTPUT clause is unlikely to make much difference here, but is probably a good idea anyway, in order to speed up the release of locks.

It's not made clear in your question exactly what secondary index you have on StatusID. As to the deadlocking, it's also not made clear what the deadlock is on, but I'm assuming it's on CurrentStatus Clustered Index only, as that would fit with having the full scan.
Then you have the Halloween Problem.
Because you are modifying the StatusID column, the compiler thinks a row previously read might reappear later in the range seek. You and I know this is not true, because @oldStatus and @newStatus are different, but the server has no logic to check for that even if you specify WHERE @oldStatus <> @newStatus.
So it demands a blocking phase in order to use the Non-clustered Index, which is costed higher than the full Clustered Index scan, which is again probably a mistake either way, as that only makes sense if the number of rows in @batchSize is large (so the Sort is slow).
You have two options as I see it:

The simplest is to just slap on a FORCESEEK hint, which means it will use the index you want, but add a Sort. This shouldn't be a problem if the number of rows is small, but in larger batches this can also be very problematic.

UPDATE TOP (@batchSize) cs
SET StatusID = @newstatus,
    UpdateDate = GETDATE()
  
OUTPUT inserted.ObjectID, inserted.StatusID, GETDATE()
  INTO StatusHistory (ObjectId, StatusID, UpdateDate)

FROM CurrentStatus cs WITH (FORCESEEK)
WHERE StatusID = @oldStatus;


Use dynamic SQL, which means the compiler can see the new and old values directly and infer they are different. This can be fairly involved: you need to make sure to escape injected strings (in this case they are numbers), and pass through any other parameters (such as strings) properly using sp_executesql.

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(N'
UPDATE TOP (@batchSize) CurrentStatus
SET StatusID = ', @newStatus, N',
    UpdateDate = GETDATE()
  
OUTPUT inserted.ObjectID, inserted.StatusID, GETDATE()
  INTO StatusHistory (ObjectId, StatusID, UpdateDate)

WHERE StatusID = ', @oldStatus, ';');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@batchSize bigint',
    @batchSize = @batchSize;

db<>fiddle

As mentioned, I see no reason why not to combine into a single command with OUTPUT directly into StatusHistory. This will speed up the release of locks, and simplify the code by removing the explicit transaction. Do be aware this won't work if StatusHistory has triggers.
This won't make a difference to the deadlocking: it still needs to access CurrentStatus first and StatusHistory second, so you should make sure all other code does the same.
If the deadlock is on CurrentStatus only, as I suspect, then my other points address that and changing the OUTPUT will have no effect on that.

Nice writeup. Just wondering, since this is an update operation, wouldn't any index seek still need to be followed by a clustered index lookup no matter how many included columns were present? I think the index on just (StatusId) would be useful and even the preferred lookup route if @batchSize is significantly less than the total row count. If the search included an ORDER BY UpdateDate (to get the oldest pending work items), then index on (StatusId, UpdateDate) is best. I see no need to explicitly include the PK (or clustered index key), since that is implicitly included in any index.

Interesting. Learned something new today. So if I update a million rows selected via an index, the index covers the updated column, and my new value equals the old value ... no update is actually applied?  As a side question, would an update trigger still fire against all of the rows? I have occasionally included a "new value(s) are different from old value(s)" condition in my update operations - especially for mass-refresh type operations. Sounds like SQL Server does that for me to some extent.

Pretty sure the update trigger fires regardless of whether the value changes.

I think it's more for the storage engine to know whether to actually go ahead and make the change, the rows still flow through the plan as normal.

Thank you for such a detailed response.  I'll have to go dig up some of the deadlock graphs.  One piece that was also elided out of my question was that the @worklist table of ids is needed to go actually do the work of that job step.  I need that short list of objectids to work on.  If I could have 2 OUTPUT clauses...

@TN  A bit more testing shows you are right, it doesn't need the INCLUDE columns, just the two options are enough.

Ok, just serialize those batches and move on with your life.
DECLARE @worklist TABLE (ObjectID bigint)
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TOP (@batchSize) CurrentStatus with (tablockx) SET StatusID=@newstatus, UpdateDate=GetDATE()
OUTPUT inserted.ObjectID into @worklist
WHERE StatusID=@oldStatus

INSERT INTO StatusHistory
SELECT ObjectID, @newStatus, GetDATE()
FROM @worklist
COMMIT TRANSACTION


This is the way. Add with (tablockx) to the update statement.

If it’s slow, then the indexes or plan need to change.  And it will resolve the deadlock because both sessions need an incomparable lock at the beginning.  So it’s similar to adding sp_getapplock at the beginning of the transaction.

@Charlieface - With the SELECT TOP (@batchSize) limit and the WHERE StatusID=@oldStatus condition, I see no reason why the database engine wouldn't make quick use of a index on (StatusID) followed by a limited number of clustered index lookups to access and update the selected rows. Should be pretty speedy to select and update a relatively small number of rows (OP mentioned 50 or 200), even if the total row count is quite large. No table scan should be necessary.
